# How to reference page when I select option value?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I use php code to create one shopping cart. When I click in product page, Since the database have more products that use php code to create product page.

Now, I can ten product in one page. But I need a select box to change product quantity in one page. **How can I do for it?**

This is my code.
Select Box code.

```
$content .= "<span style=\"margin-left:50px;color:#BE1E2D;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;\">show
<select name=\"show_num_select\">
<option value=\"10\">10</option>
<option value=\"20\">20</option>
<option value=\"30\">30</option>
<option value=\"50\">50</option>
<option value=\"100\">100</option>
</select>
item each page</span>";
```

Read select box value.

```
$show_num_select = isset($_GET['show_num_select'])?$_GET['show_num_select']:"10";
```

Create product page. n is product type. Product::count_all is a function.

```
if(empty($_GET['n'])){
$page = !empty($_GET['page'])? (int)$_GET['page']:1;
$per_page = $show_num_select;
$total_count = Product::count_all(true);
if(empty($_GET['page']) || (int)$_GET['page'] > ceil($total_count / $per_page) ){
$page = 1;
}
```

Comment: Using AJAX if you want no page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you read the data from the database or another data source. If you use an SQL related data source, use something like:

```
SELECT id, product_title FROM product LIMIT :start,:end
```

Where ":start" is the current page number (times) $per_page and ":end" is just $per_page.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a count of current items shown and use it to improve the fetch by querying only for items apart from the ones already rendered. Using ajax fetch the next set of items and render that section.  Just a suggestion to avoid fetching all items.

Avoiding page refresh will be good from users point of view.